# FontFamily is not a system font and has not been loaded through Font.loadAsync. - React Native

Tags: react-native

I can't change mt app fontfamily. I'd tried so much things from searching in google. I want to change the fontfamily of the app fonts. please help.

below is my added fonts:
[image]

Below is the react-native.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {}, // grouped into "project"
    },
    assets: ["./assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using expo project, You should use this package to load the fonts inside the project

```
expo install expo-font
```

I have made a Snack Example of "Sarpanch" custom font working

https://snack.expo.dev/DENUcVd2U